# Web.config transform applies partially

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, web-deployment

In my **web.Release.config** I have three transformations defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(directory)">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(dll)" />
    </httpCompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Both previewing transformation applied / publishing shows that only the compilation tag is being transformed.

Can't understand why **httpCompression** / **scheme** tags stay unchanged?

Here's an excerpt from the original **web.config** contents:

```
<httpCompression directory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%IIS_BIN%\gzip.dll" />
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lexeme your code is incorrect. Please try this code below:

```
 <system.webServer>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: This is true. God bless you;)